# Index sorting Elasticsearch

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-template

Could Elasticsearch Template be used to do index sorting
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/index-modules-index-sorting.html

Comment: Hi mitz, welcome to stack overflow, please edit your question to include the code you're presently using which is generating the error you've provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your question targets Spring Data Elasticsearch as you tagged it correspondingly.

Spring Data Elasticsearch currently does not support managing index templates, theres is [a ticket in Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-612) to support this.

You can of course add the index templates manually in ES like shown in Val's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [index sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/index-modules-index-sorting.html) is like any other settings and can be specified in an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/indices-templates.html):

```
PUT _template/mytemplate
{
    "index_patterns": ["myindex"],
    "aliases": {},
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards": 2,
            "number_of_replicas": 1,
            "sort.field" : "date", 
            "sort.order" : "desc" 
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "date": {
                "type": "date"
            }
        }
    }
}
```